# Is it possible for the reaction $\pi^+ \, \pi^- \rightarrow \nu_e \, \bar{\nu}_e$ to occur? If so, how would this happen?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, weak-interaction, pions

The reaction doesn't violate any conservation laws that came to my mind - however I am having trouble thinking of how it might occur.

Comment: You annihilate the pion pair to a Z which then decays to a neutrino and anti-neutrino pair

Comment: @Triatticus That one is s-channel. Another possibility for the same order in t-channel: on one side $\pi^+ \rightarrow e^+ \nu_e $ then the virtual positron annihilates with $\pi^-$ and gives a $\bar{\nu}_e$.

Comment: Yep, there are other diagrams which yield similar results, I was just suggesting one of them to show it was feasible

Comment: @Triatticus That response would work better as an answer than a comment.

Comment: @Triatticus it is the quarks that interact weakly, there will be left over quarks and not a simple z  into neutrino antineutrino.

Comment: This is true but it still produces the wanted result, this is one reason I left it as a comment and didn't expand on it much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want only neutrino antineutrino in the end , there has to be  *two weak* vertices  so that the baryon number carried by the quarks  can become zero in the neutrino antineutrino final state.

The pi+ is composed of an up and an antidown quark, the pi- of an antiup and a down quark. The [pion decays](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/piondec.html) because the quarks and antiquarks annihilate into a W with the weak interaction.  The electron mode is [inhibited,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/hadron.html) the muon channel is the observed  decay.

Then one is left with the need of a diagram that will annihilate the W+ on the W- .

a)  [WWZ vertex,](https://indico.in2p3.fr/event/622/contributions/37536/attachments/30162/37121/DiBoson2.pdf) will do the job,  and then the Z can go into any pair production in the usual way.

Searching, the WWZ vertex seems to be a matter of research both [experimental](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2058821/files/ATL-PHYS-PROC-2015-115.pdf) and theoretical. There it states:

> In the SM, only charged triple gauge boson couplings are allowed,  while neutral ones do not exist.

So any observation of a WWZ coupling that would create just a neutrino antineutrino pair is  not allowed in the standard model, it would be an indications of new physics.

b) As OktayDoğangün notes in the comments, there is another diagram, when a W+ and W_ are involved, coming from the pions decays:

[image: W+W_ tchannel]

This can have  the electron channel within the standard model,( by-passing the inhibition of pion decay, as no on shell electrons exist) and will give a neutrino antineutrino pair. As the interaction involves four weak vertices, the probability of its happening will be very small.

Comment: WWZ is not the only way to get a neutrino-antineutrino pair. If the pions annihilate to W's then they can exchange a virtual electron and produce the neutrino pair.

Comment: @OktayDoğangün  Yes, thanks I think so. I will edit